# The ubuntu machine do not get restart using reboot command

Tags: 14.04

I have tried to reboot my REMOTE MACHINE ubuntu 14.04 and therefore given `sudo reboot` command as root user.

COMMAND PROMPT gives output :

```
Broadcast message from root@"machine name" (/dev/pts/0) at 5:25 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW! root@"machine name":/#
```

Now the command prompt freezes and I cannot access the machine remotely. (i guess, it gets shut down instead of reboot) I cannot physically access the machine right now, therefore please help.

[image: Please see snapshot]
Update: when i ping the ip then the reply is coming however when i try to conect using putty or filezilla then it says connection refused

Comment: It may be running disk check at boot time of Ubuntu (automatic disk check). If so, you will have to wait until it finishes. Try to access again in 1-2 hours.

Comment: is there any way i can verify that is machine doing something (automatic disk check) or just stucked?

Comment: No, unless you are using a VPS service in which provides console management of your server.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are still the correct ones? Did you perhaps change an ssh setting which is now preventing your access?  Do you, on the off chance, have teamviewer or some other remote log in installed?

Comment: if by credentials you mean ip, user and psd then ip is correct, I have correct user id and password too, However when i try connect this server using putty it do not reach the stage where it asks for user / psd. it do not connect to the server and i gives error : connection refused. I tried it with Filezilla (correct ip, user and password) it gives me same error.

Comment: Can you make a nmap scan of your remote server `sudo nmap -n -PN -sT -sU -p- remote_server` and give the output on the question?

Comment: Was this problem resolved?

Comment: no not resolved

Answer (score 1):

If it is a remote machine that you are rebooting, you will have to establish the remote connection again as it will get disconnected during the rebooting process.

Comment: And not forgetting: the remote machine may NOT reboot at all. There may be a CD/DVD in the drive, an HDD error (which it is still trying to fix), or some other panic message during startup.

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I am sure it do not have cd/dvd in the drive.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: If for some reason it do not reebot at all, then what are the possible options to fix it (start the machine) without physically accessing machine.

Comment: If it is switched off, I don't know what can be done without an access to the machine.

Comment: No still showing connection refused while connecting through putty

Comment: is there any way i can verify that the machine doing something (like automatic disk check) or it got just switched off ?

Comment: Try 'ping' ing the remote machine

Comment: Reply is coming when i ping the ip

Comment: That is good. It means your remote PC is ON. Try doing putty again.

Comment: error putty shpowing is
PuTTY Fatal Error
---------------------------
Network error: Connection refused

Comment: Strange. If it is 'ping'ing then your remote PC is ON. Try doing ssh or any other remote access tool. Also check if you are doing Putty correctly.

Comment: I tried using filezilla.... same error

Comment: How are you 'ping'ing the remote PC? Are you using the remote PC's IP address? Use the same address for Putty or Filezilla.

Comment: yes ip is same at all three places (while pining/putty/Filezilla) using same user/psd on filezilla as i used to enter on putty cmd prompt when it was connecting.

Comment: is it a case when system is doing some disk check while rebooting or something similar to it? although its 2-3 hrs now.

Comment: Take a snapshot of the ping screen, edit your original post and paste the snapshot there.

Comment: snapshot is added

Comment: Everything seems good in ping to me. Let us wait for someone to come up with a better way.